# How to set df_print to tibble in markdown for a single R code chunk

Tags: r-markdown, tibble

I would like to show, in an rmarkdown document, the printed output of a tibble as shown in the console. i.e.

- First line: dimension summary;
- then the column headers;
- then classes of variables;
- then first 10 lines of the tibble;
- then number of rows not shown.

However, by default, tibbles and other data.frame objects are automatically converted to a tabbed, paginated table showing all contents.

I note that the option to turn off this default behaviour can be [set for a whole markdown document](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/1.10/topics/output_format) by changing the `df_print` option to `tibble` in the YAML.

However, how do I set the `df_print` option to `tibble` for just a single R code chunk, so that I can show in an Rmarkdown document what the user will see on the console?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to touch the global setting. You can explicitly call the print function  `tibble:::print.tbl_df(df)`

Example:

---

````
title: "Untitled"
author: "TC"
date: "7/27/2018"
output: 
  html_document:
    df_print: "kable"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## print tibble

```{r}
df <- tibble::as.tibble(mtcars)

tibble:::print.tbl_df(head(df))
```

## print kable (set in YAML header)

```{r}
head(df)
```
````

[output html](https://tcgriffith.github.io/cosx_exps/test52.html)

Comment: I don't think this solutions works anymore (as of May 2022).  `tibble:::print.tbl_df(as_tibble(iris))` returns the error "Error in NextMethod() : 'NextMethod' called from an anonymous function"